# What site should I post questions about Dynamics CRM 2011 configuration on?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There is a lot of customization that can be done in [Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM) that is totally out of the box, but not programming-related per se. Should I use Stack Overflow, or possibly *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)* or maybe something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the customization is specific to setting up Dynamics CRM, you'd have better luck finding a Dynamics CRM forum to ask your questions on instead.

However, if your question is related to the code used while customizing Dynamics CRM, you'd probably get better answers here. (I can't remember the language used, but I want to say it was Visual Basic or something based on the .NET framework.)

Stack Overflow is full of programmers, so we can answer questions about programming, however very few programmers are exposed to Dynamics CRM, so they are probably not able to help you configuring Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Daryl says that Dynamics CRM customization is not programming, which would make it specifically off-topic for SO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey There is a lot of customization in Dynamics that allows you to write your own code snippets, which is why I mentioned that if the customization you needed help with was writing code snippets, then it should be fine here.

Comment: Questions that are code related I'm already putting on SO.  Some other non-programmers on my team have configuration questions, but I have yet to find a site that is as easy to use that is specifically CRM.  I'm starting to feel like WebApps would be a better place for these configuration, non-programming, questions.  Although you have to be given administrative rights to be able to make the changes that they are making, so they're slightly more than just power users...

Comment: @Daryl For configuring GP, the best bet is to talk to your local representative about it, although if that's not an option I've found some solutions [on the Dynamics forums](http://community.dynamics.com/product/gp/f/32.aspx) or [on this site](http://www.gp-dynamics.com/dynamics-gp-tips-and-tricks.asp)

Comment: This CRM Specific, so your links weren't all that helpful, but it didn't take too much effort to find the CRM forums (http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/f/117.aspx).  Looks like I'll have to give that a shot.  I'd prefer to keep things in the Stack Exchange space though. :(

Comment: @Daryl SO has about 10 tags and thousands of questions on CMR.  I'd  go ahead and ask the question, and see what response you get.  The worst they can do is close your question and award you the Tubleweed badge, it's not like they can fine you.